# How to do single file deletion from the multiple uploaded file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote the code to upload and display multiple files/images now i want to delete specific one from that set of files. i tried but its getting errors.

the code which i tried is giving below:-

```
previewFiles(){
    var preview = document.querySelector('#preview');
    var files   = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files;
    var imageArray = []
    for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
        imageArray.push(files[i])
    }
    if (imageArray!==null) {
        imageArray.map(images => 
            readAndPreview(images)
        )
      }
       function readAndPreview(images){

           if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(images.name) ) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
              var image = new Image();
              image.height = 100;
              image.width = 100;
              image.title = images.name;
              image.src = this.result;
              preview.append (image) 
            }, false);

            reader.readAsDataURL(images);
          }


       }
}




render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <input type="file" onChange={this.previewFiles} multiple/>
                <div><span id="preview"><br /></span></div>
                <button onClick={this.uploadHandler}>Upload!</button>
            </div>
       )
      }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the errors? One issue might be that you need to bind the `previewFiles` function.

Comment: yes i have already binded and i am getting data which all i uploaded,

Comment: i want to delete the specific files from it